# XMLHttpRequest cannot load. Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: jquery, json, xmlhttprequest

Im using this code to call json file, i checked it with jslint "Results : Valid JSON", it is correct, I used it few months, but today suddenly stopped working, the console shows this.

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.weburl.com/web/calc/filethree.js. Origin http://www.weburl.com/ is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

```
$.getJSON("http://www.weburl.com/web/calc/filethree.js",function(datathree){
        $.each(datathree, function(i,value){
        // do something
        });
        }
);
```

Im newbie in jquery, I searched some info, tried callback= , but nothing .. :/

With callback I get 404 error

```
http://www.weburl.com/web/calc/filethree.js&callback=jQuery180014668452506884933_1349693824272?_=1349693824434
```

I dont know what happened It worked prefectly yesterday :/

Comment: Try the relative URL `web/calc/filethree.js` instead of the absolute one

Comment: @devnull69 I dont know what was the problem, but now works - your advise was helpful, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I changed the url, and now Im now using relative URL , @devnull69 advise was helpfull, and now it is works. 
Solution: Try the relative URL web/calc/filethree.js instead of the absolute one – by @devnull69